# How can I put repeat in calendar event by intent ? - ANDROID

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar

I am using this code to add calendar event:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();              
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
intent.putExtra("allDay", false);
intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=DAILY");
intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
intent.putExtra("title", "A Test Event from android app");
startActivity(intent);
```

But default in calendar application REPEAT is set on Daily. What should i put to intent to change this on 'Does not repeat' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't this:

```
intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=DAILY");
```

state that you want to repeat the event on daily basis? Have you tried removing this line?

Comment: It can be... xd I will check this later, ty